# How to Segment One of Two Detected Objects Using YOLOv8

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, edge-detection, yolov8

I am working on a computer vision project that requires me to detect two objects in an image and return the measurement of only one of the objects. I have considered two approaches:

1. Use YOLOv8 object detection to detect both objects, then use edge detection to get the edges of the object and get the measurement.
2. Use YOLOv8 segmentation to segment both objects, then get the measurement of the desired object from the segmentation mask.

I am not interested in using segmentation because of the added complexity and inference time. Is there a way to segment only one of the detected objects using YOLOv8?

................................